# css styling for angular reactive form requiring form to be touched and invalid

Tags: css, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using a reactive form to allow a user to change their password. I want to style my input boxes to show the user when the form is invalid or has some error.

```
input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The problem is that this shows before the form has even been touched. I want this CSS only to apply after the form has been touched. Unsure how I can achieve this behaviour in CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the error to be shown when it has been touched, then use the aptly named `ng-touched` class

```css
input.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Can't believe it was this simple! I was sure I had tried this but clearly not, thank you!